# Build package for both node and browser environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have developed a node NPM package which is mainly a wrapper (using node's `http`, `https` and `querystring` modules) for a specific JSON API. It is build in Coffeescript and enables a Node.js server to communicate with this API. The Api is mainly REST.

Now I want this library to be also available for the browsers. This means the calls to the `http` modules needs to be replaced with `XMLHttpRequest` (asynchronous). It seems to me I would make a wrapper for the adapter. For the Node environment, this adapter would pass all the calls to the `http` module, and for the browser environment to the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Is there a nice way to make a build system so that the npm package contains both version, and I can publish the plain "browser-version" also on Github? The node package then is available via `require('package-name')` and should place a JS file (for the browser) in a directory.

I have looked in [Component](https://github.com/component/component), which is nice for client-side package managing, but the problem remains how to create different build environments.

Comment: If you are looking into Component, also take a look into http://bower.io/

Comment: Yes, thank you. I also already found Bower. It seems pretty nice. Still, the difficulty seems to be to create some kind of building environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example solution for cross-developing for node.js and browsers using browserify: https://github.com/amitayd/grunt-browserify-jasmine-node-example ([and discussion at my blog post](http://www.doboism.com/blog/2013/05/17/cross-developing-for-node-js-and-browsers-using-browserify/)) .

Specifically for having different implementations for Browser/Node.js check [PersistentReaderWriter.js](https://github.com/amitayd/grunt-browserify-jasmine-node-example/blob/master/src/common/PersistentReaderWriter.js).

Once you have some template to start working with browserify, and you're aware of some pitfalls, you might find you'd like to use it for small libraries as well.

Edit: Note that if you browserify the module, the isBrowser() check shouldn't be by checking if module and module.exports are defined, since Browserify's wrapper will define them in the module context.  Instead, in my example, I check for window to be defined.

Comment: Thank you. It think `var Utils = require('./Utils');
if (Utils.isBrowser) {...} else { ...}` is the part I was really looking for. Although I am still not really a fan of Browserify, I do like you solution.

Comment: I agree that if it's single module (single file) library and it works for you there may be no justification to switch to node.
Libraries such underscore cater for both node and browsers in a single file. 

Adding a small note about the isBrowser in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `node-browser-resolve` which adds a `browser` section to `package.json`:

```
{
  "browser": {
    "./index.js": "./browser.js"
  }
}
```

See https://nolanlawson.com/2017/01/09/how-to-write-a-javascript-package-for-both-node-and-the-browser/

Answer (score 1):

add this at the end of the module. and export your module like this.

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = YourModule;
}
else {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([], function() {
      return YourModule;
    });
  }
  else {
    window['YourModule'] = YourModule;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, although it is not what is first had in mind, with different build environments.

In my case, I had a pretty small library which were using the Node's `http`, `https`, `querystring` and `url` packages. I did not want to use something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), because it seemed not appropriate to bundle all these packages for a small api-library. Instead I replaced the `http` and `https` functionality with the [XMLHttpRequest](https://npmjs.org/package/xmlhttprequest) package. The small functionalities provided by `querystring` and `url` could easily be rewritten.

In my library I check, run-time, if the `window.XMLHttpRequest` object is available. If so, use that (native) object. Otherwise, it uses the one provided by the package. As such:

```cs
_getRequestObject: () ->
  if window? and window.XMLHttpRequest?
    return new window.XMLHttpRequest()

  if window? and window.ActiveXObject?
    try
      request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')
    catch e
      try
        request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
      catch e

  XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest
  return new XMLHttpRequest()
```

An other problem was that `exports` is not defined in the browser. There are packages to simulate this behaviour, but again, it did not want to bloat the library. So I check, again runtime, if the `module` variable is set. If so, the object I have defined is set to that, otherwise it is set to the `window` object:

```cs
if typeof module is 'undefined'
  window['My-module'] = My_module_object
else
  module.exports = exports = My_module_object
```

This all works for me, because I have no real required dependencies of Node.js which are not present in the browser environment. I am afraid that with larger projects a solution like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) is really needed, but I am still curious if there are other solutions, like creating different build-environments when packaging the library for Node.js or when for (e.g.) Bower.

Comment: Because there is more than one way to brew coffee(script): `unless module?`.